# Google Calendar API displays incorrect dateTime for correct event within timeMin & timeMax

Tags: php, datetime, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to fetch all the events on a specific day from a Google Calendar and parse the JSON using PHP.
Here's the request:
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/hvur7qeipep3ehthmqqgn3a7ng%40group.calendar.google.com/events?timeMax=2014-11-16T23%3A59%3A59-05%3A00&timeMin=2014-11-16T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&key=$api_key";

This request indeed returns the correct events on that day, however, their start times are completely different.

One event, instead of November 16, 2014, returns:
[start] => Array
                        (
                            [dateTime] => 2014-07-20T23:59:00-04:00
                            [timeZone] => America/New_York
                        )

Another returns:
[start] => Array
                        (
                            [dateTime] => 2014-08-03T10:00:00-04:00
                            [timeZone] => America/New_York
                        )

Am I looking in the wrong place for the right date?
Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: What is incorrect in the datetime? Are you sure this is not just timezone "issue" ?

Comment: The incorrect part is that both events are supposed to take place today (2014-11-16), not in July or August as they seem to be from their respective dateTimes.

Comment: Then you probably inserted them wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that these are recurring events? Any recurring event that has at least one instance in the given range will be returned. If you don't plan to do recurring event expansion, you should use singleEvents=true as a parameter.

Comment: luc, you are a genius. That solved it!